# Fedora stuck on running scriplet: systemd-libs

Tags: linux, fedora, dnf

I used the dnf update command and after some time this happened. It's been like this for half an hour. Not only that, but I can't move my mouse, press any buttons, open something else, the computer is literally frozen and I don't know what to do.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I'm posting this answer, it's been 18 hours since your question, so you've probably made this decision already — seems like the computer has crashed (possibly due to something triggered by the systemd upgrade scriptlet, maybe just an unfortunate coincidence).

At this point, the best thing to do is going to be to reboot (with the hard power button if necessary!) and then try to clean up after. `dnf check` should find the incomplete transaction and give you options to fix it.